# Minimization of constrained variable

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to perform a minimization of a variable but NMinimize[] does not seems what I need (it minimize a function, but my variable is inside a function)

I want to minimize "h" with respect to "P0" and "yp" with the following constraints:

```
 c1 <= F(h,P0,yp) <= c2
 c1 <= G(h,P0,yp) <= c2
 c1 <= H(h,P0,yp) <= c2
 c1 <= J(h,P0,yp) <= c2
 h>c5
 P0>0
 c3<yp<c4
```

I tried:

```
 NMinimize[{h,constraints},{P0,yp}]
```

but it does not work.

h,P0,yp are all variables and not functions.

Comment: Try `NMinimize[{h,constraints},{P0,yp,h}]`. For example, `NMinimize[{z, 
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 1 && x + y + z <= 4 && 
   x + y + z >= 1 && z >= 1/2 && y > 0 && x > 11/10 && x < 13/10}, {x,
   y, z}]` results in `{0.5, {x -> 1.27603, y -> 0.606337, z -> 0.5}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
F[x_, y_, z_] = x + y - z;
G[x_, y_, z_] = x - y + z;
H[x_, y_, z_] = x + y + z;
J[x_, y_, z_] = x - y - z;
c1 = 10;
c2 = 20;
c3 = 3;
c4 = 4;
c5 = 5;
NMinimize[{h, 
  c1 <= {F[h, P0, yp], G[h, P0, yp], H[h, P0, yp], J[h, P0, yp]} <= 
   c2, h > c5, P0 > 0, c3 < yp < c4}, {P0, yp, h}]
```

> `{13., {P0 -> 0., yp -> 3., h -> 13.}}`

Comment: Correct. In variables, "h" must be also placed.